# Having trouble with AWS Lambda when using pdf filler

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, pdfkit

I am having trouble using pdffiller with AWS lambda.

```
 Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at exports.execFile (child_process.js:212:15)
    at Object.fillFormWithOptions (/var/task/node_modules/pdffiller-aws-lambda/index.js:129:13)
    at Promise (/var/task/handler.js:574:21)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fillDocument (/var/task/handler.js:573:16)
    at module.exports.processDocument (/var/task/handler.js:626:27) code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

I am simply using fillFormWithOptions or fillForm function. The issue is with both of them.

```
pdfFiller.fillFormWithOptions(
            `https://unlockd-static-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${documentId}.pdf`,
            `/tmp/${listingId}_${documentId}.pdf`,
            values,
            false,
            "/tmp/",
            error => {
              if (!error) {
                resolve("Success. Pdf document is been process");
              } else {
                reject(error);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The pdffiller-aws-lambda package is pretty massive. Do you in fact have it all included in your lambda? There's a `bin` folder in the module's location, containing 2 files at a combined ~50MB size.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: If the files are missing then you need to include them. Locally you would do your `npm install`, then you'd zip up the lambda folder with those modules and upload it to your lambda.

Comment: I did that. The issue there is, pdfkt binary are required to process that command. Locally it works fine because I have these binary installed in my machine but when I deploy it to lambda. It doesn't work.